# SiC MOSFET gate resistance

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving

I am making a gate driver circuit for [SCT3160KL](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/sic/mosfet/sct3160kl-e.pdf) using this isolated gate driver IC from Texas Instruments - [UCC21750-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc21750-q1.pdf?ts=1600253383894&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fgate-drivers%252Fisolated-gate-drivers%252Fproducts.html).

The problem I'm facing is the selection of external gate resistance. I require a 2.5 A peak source current and 5 A peak sink current. According to the formula on the datasheet, my resistance turns out to be negative. (Formula in **Section 9.2.2.5 of UCC21750-q1** I suspect this is because of the SiC MOSFET's gate input resistance which I approximated as 9 ohms for 500 kHz frequency. I chose Vcc = 15 V and Vee = 0 V, to be connected by an isolated power supply (Murata).

I tried some other gate driver ICs too like [UCC5350-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc5350-q1.pdf?ts=1600232466746&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fgate-drivers%252Fisolated-gate-drivers%252Fproducts.html) **Section 9.2.2.2**

1. Is my approximation of gate input resistance off by a wide margin? I don't have an impedance analyzer.
2. Have I chosen wrong gate driver ics ?
3. Is the solution to my problem reducing source current?

[image: UCC5350-Q1]

[image: For the UCC21750-Q1]

I intend to use it at 500kHz switching frequency, and as per the datasheet page-11 the maximum frequency is 1MHz. What's the problem?

Comment: I suggest you post the formula you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry Grigoryev, I've mentioned the sections where you can find the formula.

Comment: Much easier if you just take a screenshot, crop everything but the formula, post result here. Also: I looked in Section 9.2.2.5 yet I cannot find a formula that is used to calculate a **resistance**.

Comment: I have took a look of the formula, but I can't understand how could you get negative number, it's just a quotient of positive numbers?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič If I take gate input resistance as 9 ohms then with a 15 V as VCC, I'll get a negative Rg if I want a 2.5 A source current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the formula is given in terms of source/sink current, I need to find the external gate turn-on and turn-off resistances.

Comment: it would mean, that even with 0 ohm resistors, the current won't reach 2.5A. By the way the datasheet says Rg=18 ohm and not 9, how did you get that value?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič on the datasheet R_GFETInt is 1.8 ohms. This is specific to their power transistor. For the SiCFET I'm using, I have taken it to be 9 ohm at 500 kHz. Yes I realize that it won't give 2.5 A, so what should I be changing here?

Comment: The datasheet you have linked SCT3160KL says 18ohm@1Mhz. Why it has to be 2.5A? What's the planned switching frequency?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I want to use it at 500 kHz. I assumed a linear relation, so assumed 9 ohms

Comment: It has nothing to do with linear relation, this gate driver is not suitable for such frequency.